# how to differentiate auto getclipboarddata from real content pasting?

Tags: c++, winapi, ms-office, clipboard, paste

i'm trying to dev a simple tool which notify the user when he is pasting content into an unthorized application. I ve hooked the getclipboarddata function to do this. But application like MS office launch sometimes getclipboarddata to get retrieve the content but it s not a user pasting action. How to differentiate those different calls ?

Comment: If possible, I'd take a different route such as using a private clipboard format that only the authorized applications will know how to use.

Comment: But, but, what if you want to type the text of an SO question into Word so you can spell-check it first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any clipboard viewer is going to auto-paste data into itself. This includes clipboard programs like my own ClipMate, as well as Office, various editors with clipboard history, remote desktop, VMWare, and big-brother/malware apps.
Assuming that  you're talking about plain text, there is no way to determine a user-initiated paste.  You can guess, by looking to see if Ctrl+V or Shift+Insert is pressed.  But that's pretty shaky.

Comment: If i talk about any format is there any hope ( logically not ). Thanks for replying

Comment: The keyboard check is quite flaky. It misses both the mouse popup menu as well as the main menu `Edit>Paste`.

Comment: Ye i know it would be too tricky to "spy" all user ways to paste ( in office and myabe others u can use alt + severals touches to paste )